# Add data to a table from database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am new to .net and C# and I want to perform update/delete. I am using e template which has a table. I want to get data from database and display in that table and then perform update.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
   SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
   SqlDataReader rd;   
   SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand();

   //open connection with database
   connection.Open();

   //query to select all users with the given username
   comand.CommandText = "select * from artikulli ";
   rd = comand.ExecuteReader();

   if(rd.HasRows )
   {
      while (rd.Read())
      {
         Row1.Items.Add(rd[0].ToString());
      }
   }

   connection.Close();
}
```

`Row1` is the id of table row. I know that this is not the best way and it doesn't work.

I get this error:

> CS0103: The name 'Row1' does not exist in the current context

My table row `Row1` is declared as below:

```
<td id="Row1" style="width: 73px">&nbsp;</td>
```

Comment: where is your table row `Row1` declared? could you please show us that code?

Comment: Where does `Row1` get created and set?  Nothing from your code-block indicates that `Row1` should be in context.

Comment: <td id="Row1" style="width: 73px">&nbsp;</td>

Comment: You can't use html tag inside C# code

Comment: The simplest "fix" is to add `runat="server"` in your `<td>` for `Row1`. There's a lot wrong in addition to that, however.

Comment: Why not use a `gridview` control? Instead of adding `runat=server` @mikeguthrie

Comment: @Inanikian That would be a better approach.  I was just commenting on how to resolve the compile error.  From the look of what we can see, it looks like it needs a fair bit of re-work.

Comment: because I want to use my template . How can I integrate gridview with template? @Mike tell me a better way to do it.

Comment: Well for one thing: you're creating a `SqlConnection` and a `SqlCommand` - but you're never **associating** the command with the connection! Either use `command.Connection = conn;` or use one of the constructors for the `SqlCommand` (**command** - with **two** `m`) that allows you to specify the connection to be used ...

Comment: Ok thank you. But Still it's not working

Comment: Why are you using a `<td>` and attempting to adding stuff manually? Why don't you just fetch the data from your SQL query into a `List<Something>` and then bind that to a `GridView` or some other control that can display multiple rows of data?

Comment: Yes but how to make the gridview look as my table form in template that I am using. I mean how to add class of gridview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's apparent, as you've admitted, you are new to C#, so there are a number of things to point out, as have been addressed in the comments.

- HTML elements are not going to be visible to the code-behind without the `runat="server"` attribute.  (This attribute is *required* for ASP elements.)
- As marc_s pointed out, your database communication would currently produce a run-time error, as the `SqlCommand` was not given a connection.
- At some point you must really familiarize yourself with [the using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

To correct your code-behind, it should be more like the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            //open connection with database
            connection.Open();

            //query to select all users with the given username
            command.CommandText = "select * from artikulli ";

            List<object> users = new List<object>();

            using (SqlDataReader rd = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (rd.HasRows)
                {
                    while (rd.Read())
                    {
                        users.Add(rd[0].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }

            myGridView.DataSource = users;
            myGridView.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Where `myGridView` is an instance of a [`GridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) created in the aspx page.  The list `users` should be a list of whatever class you want to create to show user data, which will determine how your `GridView` instance will be formatted.

Just to get you to the point where you can see your database query working at all you can instead do the following from your query result (though I definitely recommend implementing the `GridView` eventually):

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
using (SqlDataReader rd = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (rd.HasRows)
    {
        while (rd.Read())
        {
            sb.Append(rd[0].ToString());
            sb.Append("<br />");
        }
    }
}
Row1.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
```

And you will have to change your `Row1` to

```
<td id="Row1" style="width: 73px" runat="server">&nbsp;</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the error, you'll need to bring your Row1 variable into scope

```
TableRow Row1 = new TableRow();
while (rd.Read())
{
   Row1.Items.Add(rd[0].ToString());
   Table1.Rows.Add(Row1);
}
```

Comment: `CommandType.Text` is the default - it doesn't need to be set explicitly.

Comment: @marc_s -- thanks -- didn't realize -- I mostly use stored procs.